# ExtJS: Destroy window with config 'closeAction' set to 'hide'

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I have a window with [`closeAction`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-closeAction) configured to `'hide'` on instantiation:

```
var myWin = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    ...
    closeAction:'hide',
    ...
});
```

Calling `close()` on `myWin` therefore simply hides the window. I need to *destroy* the window in the sense of `destroy` as implied by the Sencha docs:

> remove the window from the DOM and destroy it and all descendant
>   Components. The window will not be available to be redisplayed via the
>   show method.

*What did I try?* I tried:

1. calling `destroy` directly on the window object:

   ```
   myWin.destroy();
   ```
2. setting `closeAction` to `destroy` prior to calling `close()`:

   ```
   win.closeAction='destroy';
   win.close();
   ```

In both cases, `myWin` is simply hidden rather than destroyed. Any thoughts?

Comment: With `destroy()` it is perfectly destroyed: http://jsfiddle.net/5BcBd/1/.

Comment: @VisioN Thank you for your comment. How are you checking whether it's simply hidden or actually destroyed? In my case, I'm able to re-show the window, that's why I ascertain it's hidden and not destroyed.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle in the comment above so that is displays the contents of `body` before and after removal. Typically you may use Chrome DevTools or Firebug for that. In case of `destroy()` the DOM structure is removed and if you try to call `show()` afterwards, the JS will raise an error.

Comment: Indeed you're right; please add this as answer, stating clearly that what I assert about `destroy()` in my question is incorrect - I'll mark your answer as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Method `destroy()` should successfully remove the window object from the DOM. In order to illustrate this you can check the basic example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BcBd/1/).

After calling `myWin.destroy()` the structure is cleared and it becomes not possible to reinvoke the window with `myWin.show()`.

Answer (score 3):

Are you want to destroy the window.use below code

```
Ext.getCmp('Window Id').destroy();
```